# Difference between "consent" and "acquiescence"

Tags: differences

What is the difference between *consent* and *acquiescence*?

Comment: You might want to look up both words in a dictionary.

Comment: @RichardKayser Hi, Richard. I did but to me, both seemed similar and I'm sorry that I'm not able to distinguish the nuances of the two and unable to get a clear idea. Therefore, I request your help. Thank you so much.

Comment: From Lexico: Consent -- permission for something to happen or agreement to do something. Acquiescence -- the reluctant acceptance of something without protest. Consent involves okaying or agreeing to something. Acquiescence involves reluctantly accepting something without protesting.